# How to minimize mesh in large tessellated pattern

Tags: remesh

I have a large amount of fine nurbs paths I have converted to meshes, pictured below.
[image]
[image]

These are layed on top of a flat surface, creating an embossed pattern. They span quite a large portion of my assembly. The end goal is to 3d print the model, so I have converted these paths into meshes. However, a normal conversion creates a large amount of subdivisions, and the the huge amount of resulting elements makes the files larger than 2gb and unworkable. I have tried decimating, which broke the geometry, and remeshing, none of which worked, even with max octree depth. Tried scaling the object up 100x, and then performing remeshes as well to no avail.

How can I simplify this mesh? I dont need the final representation to be incredibly detailed, in fact quite simple blocks would suffice since it so small. Is there some other way to convert the path to a mesh, perhaps with a non-cylindrical profile to be easier represented? Or a better workflow to achieve this pattern?

Thank you!

Comment: When you say 'pattern', is that a filigree (with holes), or a pattern on another surface?

Comment: These meshes are layed on top of another surface, creating an embossed pattern. Will update description!